# Can I copy individual stages of a SharePoint 2013 list-based workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, workflow, copy

I have a SP 2013 list with a list-based workflow. Next release, I create a new list with the same content type. I want to re-use the list-based workflow but must implement a work-around to do this. I want to simply copy the stages in the first workflow into a new workflow and then associate the new workflow to the new list. It seems to work. Do you know of any issues doing this?

I cannot work with a reusable workflow because that does not recognize the content type fields and in 2013 you cannot successfully base a workflow on a content type.

Thanks,
Linda

Answer (score 0):

You can copy individual stages of a SharePoint 2013 list-based workflow, but it will copy the actions and part of settings in it.

If there is some custom variables, settings in the single task and so on, these will not be copied. It depends on your workflow actions